# Java - Need my loop to not only end after three guesses but display the correct number as well

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to have my loop only occur three times. So if the user doesn't guess the correct number after their third guess then the loop ends which I have but it doesn't display what the number was. I need the number displayed after the third guess but not sure why it's not displaying the correct number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GuessNumberDoWhileA {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //Generate random number from 1-10
    int number = (int) (Math.random()*9 + 1);
    int count = 0;
    //Auto Generated Method stub
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Tell the user to guess a number
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
    
    //int guess = -1;
    
    //while (guess != number) {
      while (count < 3) {   
        count++;
        
        
        System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
        int guess = Input.nextInt();
        
        if (guess == number)
            System.out.println("Correct the number was " + number);
        else if (guess > number)
            System.out.println("Your guess is to high try again!");
        else if (guess < number)
            System.out.println("Your guess is to low try again!");
        else 
            System.out.println("The correct number is " + number);
    }
            System.out.println("The number was " + number);

}
```

}

Comment: In which case do you expect to print `"The correct number is " + number`? A `guess` can be either equal to `number`, greater than it or lower. There is no 4th option.

Comment: @Amongalen that's exactly what I need. If they don't guess it on one of the three guesses there's no fourth guess, just display what the number was.

Comment: That's what the `System.out.println("The number was " + number);` outside the loop is for. What you need is an additional condition in your loop that doesn't force additional guesses if you already got the number right. Currently you go through all three guesses even if the first or second guess was already correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `boolean` variable that can be used to check whether user was able to guess the number correctly or not. Initial value of this boolean variable should be `false`.

You don't need the last `else` statement in the loop. If user guesses the number correctly, set the `boolean` variable to `true` and break out of the loop. After the loop, check if the `boolean` variable is `false` or not. If it is `false`, that means user was not able to guess the number, so display the correct number to the user.

If user is able to guess the number then the first `if` statement in the loop will print the correct number on the console and break out of the loop. It will also set the boolean variable to `true`, so correct number will be printed only once on the console.

```
boolean guessed = false;
    
while (count < 3) {   
    count++;
        
    System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
    int guess = Input.nextInt();
        
    if (guess == number) {
        System.out.println("Correct the number was " + number);
        guessed = true;
        break;
    }
    else if (guess > number)
        System.out.println("Your guess is to high try again!");
    else if (guess < number)
        System.out.println("Your guess is to low try again!");
}
    
if (!guessed) System.out.println("Number was: " + number);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Now I know why even when I guessed it the loop kept on going. Thanks a bunch! I still have much to learn!